# How do I adjust the textview position in Android ? (for subtitle)

Tags: android, css, textview, android-xml

I'm using textview to show subtitle with my video, whatever i tried i couldn't find the stabil position. i couldn't put the textview to bottom of the screen. I want to control bottom padding of textview. It is hard to explain, Let me explain with screenshots. Maybe it is easy, but i couldn't find the solution.
Hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

**Here is my Xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/MainView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/SurfaceView"
    android:layout_width="321dp"
    android:layout_height="462dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/textView1"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:shadowColor="#000000"
   android:shadowDx="4"
   android:shadowDy="4"
   android:shadowRadius="4"
   android:text=""
   android:textColor="#F2F2F2"
   android:textSize="23px"
   android:textStyle="bold" />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

**Here are the screenshots :**

**Two line textview (My Screen)**
[image]

**One line textview (My Screen)**
[image]

**That's what i want when it is two line**
[image]

**That's what i want when it is one line**
[image]

Comment: Use `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: I already use. I edited my question(XML) please look.

Comment: I did, please check again.

Answer (score 0):

On top of video frame center horizontal and center vertical some container for TextView (for example RelativeLayout), set horizontal and vertical margins for the container and place your TextView to the bottom of the container with following addition attributes:

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
```

Comment: Try to use FrameLayout instead of RelativeLayout for overlay SurfaceView.

Comment: I mean to place the container and SurfaceView in FrameLayout instead of RelativeLayout.

Comment: Sorry it is not working too. Maybe i did wrong can you edit your post please.

Comment: I set the `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` `android:layout_height="200px"` `android:maxHeight="30px"` now position of `two line` is ok, but one line is still slightly up. I want to set padding of `one line` just like `last line of two line` . Any idea ?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I can not understand what your want to do, why you tell about paddings without margins and why you think about two lines instead of one TextView with one text string and so on...

Comment: Thank you for your answer,I think i did explain myself wrong. I'm using one textview it is dividing into two lines automatically according to subtitle. in brief: When subtitle pass two line from one line, I want to set position of first line a little further down,because lets say first line's position is 10px up from bottom while two lines and when it passes to one line from two lines, first line is still 10px up from bottom. really it is hard to explain. hope you can understand my problem.